# CodePipeline not saving all files in source artifacts

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I've set up a new pipeline in AWS CodePipeline, and connected it to my GitHub account. I'm getting build errors in CodeBuild because a folder that is in my GitHub repository, static/css/, is missing (I'm using CodeBuild to do a gatsby build).

This is not a folder generated in the build process - this folder and its files exist in a clean repo. I've also checked that the branch is correct (master).

When I inspect the zip file in the SourceArtifacts folder in my S3 bucket, this folder is not there.

Any ideas why CodePipeline is not retrieving, or at least keeping, this subfolder and its contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the missing folder was listed with an export-ignore attribute in the .gitattributes folder. The static/css folder got zipped up with everything else after removing this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Github repo and select the Green button "Clone or Download", then download the zip file. This is essentially what CodePipeline is doing to get your Github source. Now inspect the files in the zip file and confirm if 'static' directory is there. If it is not there you need to fix that and get the files into github.

Comment: No, I checked that before I posted my question, but thanks for the suggestion.